# How can I check the success/error callbacks of an AJAX request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We can put AJAX callback in those places:

```
$.ajax(url,{
   data:data,
   ...,
   success:successCallback1,
   error:errorCallback1
})
.success(successCallback2)
.error(errorCallback2)
.done(successCallback3)
.fail(errorCallback3)
.complete(complateCallback1)
```

And my response is

```
{success:true,data:XYZ} or {success:false,message:'abc'}   
//xyz is string or an json object
```

I want to set the default callback when success or error. It means:

- If none of `successCallback1`/`successCallback2`/`successCallback3` was provided. Then run my default `successCallbackDefault`.
- If either of them was provided, not run my `successCallbackDefault`.
- And the same as `errorCallbackDefault` of `errorCallback1`/`errorCallback2`/`errorCallback3`.

The `successCallbackDefault` and `errorCallbackDefault` is:

```
function successCallbackDefault(res){
   if(!res.success){
       showTips(data.message || 'Fail!');
   }else if(!res.data){ //if no data responsed, show a success message
       showTips('Success!');
   }
}

function errorCallbackDefault(){
    showTips(data.message || 'Fail!');
}
```

Then we can use

```
//this will run successCallbackDefault
$.post(url,{data:data})   

//this will run successCallback1(not successCallbackDefault)
$.post(url,{data:data,success:successCallback1})  

//this will run successCallback2(not successCallbackDefault)
$.post(url,{data:data}).success(successCallback2)

//this will run successCallback3(not successCallbackDefault)
$.post(url,{data:data}).done(successCallback2)
```

To override the successCallback1 with successCallbackDefault, we can use `$.ajaxSetup` or `$.ajaxPrefilter` or the `beforeSend` option of `$.ajax`.

But HOW and WHERE to check if the user has provided `successCallback2` or `successCallback3`?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution at last. It can work very well to fit all my requirement.

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event,xhr,options) {
        if(options.success){
               xhr.hasSuccessCallback=true;
        }else{
               var _done=xhr.done;
               xhr.success=xhr.done=function(func){
                   if(!func){return;}
                   xhr.hasSuccessCallback=true;
                   _done(func);
                  return xhr;
               };
        }
        if(options.error){
               xhr.hasErrorCallback=true;
        }else{
               var _fail=xhr.fail;
               xhr.error=xhr.fail=function(func){
                   if(!func){return;}
                   xhr.hasErrorCallback=true;
                   _fail(func);
                   return xhr;
               };
        }
}).ajaxSuccess(function (event,xhr,options,data) {
        if(xhr.hasSuccessCallback){return;}
        console.log('default success callback');        
}).ajaxError(function (event,xhr,options,error) {
        if(xhr.hasErrorCallback){return;}
        console.log('default error callback');
});
```

And the testcase as below:

```
function buildFuncs(type,places){
    $.each(places,function(i,place){
        window[type+'_in_'+place]=function(){console.log(type+' in '+place);};
    });
}

buildFuncs('success',['option','done','success']);
buildFuncs('error',['option','error','fail']);

//to print a sperate line between each testcase
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(){
     console.log('---------------');
});

$.get(self.location.href);
$.get(self.location.href,success_in_option);
$.get(self.location.href).success(success_in_success);
$.get(self.location.href,success_in_option).success(success_in_success);
$.get(self.location.href).done(success_in_done);
$.get(self.location.href,success_in_option).done(success_in_done);
$.get(self.location.href).success(success_in_success).done(success_in_done);
$.get(self.location.href,success_in_option).success(success_in_success).done(success_in_done);


$.get(self.location.href+'ABC');
$.ajax(self.location.href+'ABC',{error:error_in_option});
$.get(self.location.href+'ABC').error(error_in_error);
$.ajax(self.location.href+'ABC',{error:error_in_option}).error(error_in_error);
$.get(self.location.href+'ABC').fail(error_in_fail);
$.ajax(self.location.href+'ABC',{error:error_in_option}).fail(error_in_fail);
$.get(self.location.href+'ABC').error(error_in_error).fail(error_in_fail);
$.ajax(self.location.href+'ABC',{error:error_in_option}).error(error_in_error).fail(error_in_fail);
```

the result for success testcase output:

```
default success callback
---------------
success in success
---------------
success in option
---------------
success in option
success in success
---------------
success in done
---------------
success in option
success in done
---------------
success in success
success in done
---------------
success in option
success in success
success in done
---------------
```

and the same as error testcase.